# jQuery transform rotation not acting as expected

Tags: jquery, css, webkit, jquery-animate, css-transforms

I am trying to rotate an element clockwise 90 degrees on mouseover, and return it to its original position on mouseout.

Making this happen is simple enough, but when I try to use the `.animate()` function to make it seem like a transition, nothing happens.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/efg61ywc/) that may help you understand what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use `.animate()` just use `.css()` and CSS3.

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/efg61ywc/2/)**

```
$('i.brand').hover(function () {
      rotation += 90;
      $(this).animateRotate(rotation);
 }, function () {
      rotation -= 90;
      $(this).animateRotate(rotation);
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.brand{
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Concise and a perfect solution.